# copying filenames from files of one folder to files of another via bash

Tags: bash, rename

I have many different folders with the exact same amount of files in the exact same order. 
e.g.:

```
Folder1              Folder2            Folder3
  AFile.jpg            9001.jpg           13004.jpg
  BFile.jpg            9002.jpg           13005.jpg
  Cfile.jpg            9003.jpg           13006.jpg
```

I want to copy the filenames of Folder1 to every other folder, so that the outcome is:

```
Folder1              Folder2            Folder3
  AFile.jpg            AFile.jpg          AFile.jpg
  BFile.jpg            BFile.jpg          BFile.jpg
  Cfile.jpg            Cfile.jpg          Cfile.jpg
```

However, every suggestion to rename multiple files only renames multiple files using the same replacement string.

Is there a possibility to do this via a bash script?

Comment: How are you mapping? Is there any particular order ?

Comment: The Files are ordered by Number continuously within one folder, however not continuously throughout different folders

Comment: Whatever the order may be , just run a loop to list the files in the first folder , extract the names and store it into an array. Next loop the other folders and inside the loop assign the new file name from the array.  Get the idea. ?

Comment: thats is so simple, why havent I thought about that.... I will report back if I got it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some test directories and files, just to show one way of doing it.

Create the directories.

```
mkdir Folder{1..3}
```

Create the files inside the directories.

```
touch Folder1/{A..C}file.jpg
touch Folder2/{9001..9003}.jpg
touch Folder3/{13004..13006}.jpg
```

Check the files.

```
ls Folder{1..3}
```

The output

```
Folder1:
Afile.jpg  Bfile.jpg  Cfile.jpg

Folder2:
9001.jpg  9002.jpg  9003.jpg

Folder3:
13004.jpg  13005.jpg  13006.jpg
```

The script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

f1=(Folder1/*.jpg)  

 for dir in Folder{2..3}; do
   ( cd "$dir/" || exit; files=(*.jpg); for i in "${!f1[@]}"; do mv -v ${files[$i]}" "${f1[$i]##*/}"; done )
 done
```

The output of the script.

```
renamed '9001.jpg' -> 'Afile.jpg'
renamed '9002.jpg' -> 'Bfile.jpg'
renamed '9003.jpg' -> 'Cfile.jpg'
renamed '13004.jpg' -> 'Afile.jpg'
renamed '13005.jpg' -> 'Bfile.jpg'
renamed '13006.jpg' -> 'Cfile.jpg'
```

Check the files again.

```
ls Folder{1..3}
```

The output

```
Folder1:
Afile.jpg  Bfile.jpg  Cfile.jpg

Folder2:
Afile.jpg  Bfile.jpg  Cfile.jpg

Folder3:
Afile.jpg  Bfile.jpg  Cfile.jpg
```

---

A brief explanation
 Save the *.jpg files in an array from Folder1

```
f1=(Folder1/*.jpg)
```

- cd  inside Folder2 and Folder3 using a loop and exit if cd fails so the script will exit immediately.
- save the `*.jpg` files inside folder2 and folder3 in an array named `files` `files=(*.jpg)`
- Loop through the indices of `f1` and `files` arrays the `!` from `"${!f1[@]}"` is what does it.

The `"${f1[$i]##*/}"` a form of P.E. (Parameter Expansion) which strips the path name from the file name.

The code inside the `( )` runs in a subshell so you don't have to go back in the previous directory where you started the script.

```
( cd "$dir"/ || exit; files=(*.jpg); for i in "${!f1[@]}"; do mv -v  "${files[$i]}" "${f1[$i]##*/}"; done )
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, once I removed the quotation marks. Thank you for the elaborate reply and explanation!!!